# This error blocked my entire project (the ->where() error)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this line:

```
$messages= [DB::table('Messages')->where('Column1','Home')->get('Column2')];
```

I get this error from laravel-5 "Call to a member function where() on a non-object"

I get this error **from all the files I have DB:table and ->where...** so i can't do anything until I get rid of thie error  :(  (This is why I'm asking the question again; I asked yesterday, but I got no answer)

I have this:  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` If i switch to `use DB;` I get the error "The use statement with non-compound name 'DB' has no effect"

What could be the cause of this problem ?

Thanks.